# I cant read file from ftp server, FTP Streaming Inbound Channel Adapter

Tags: java, spring, ftp, spring-integration

I want to use FTP Streaming Channel Adapter for very simple example read files from ftp server, I read the documentation but it is not clear to me,
I managed to write files to the ftp server reading an example but, i cant obtain reading files as `InputStream`

```
<int:gateway service-interface="ftpmodule.service.FileWriterFTP"
    default-request-channel="ftpOutChannel"/>

<int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter
    session-factory="ftpClientFactory" channel="ftpOutChannel"
    remote-directory="/web/" remote-filename-generator-expression="headers['fileName']">
</int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

and my classes

```
 public interface FileWriterFTP {

   public void write(@Header("fileName") String fileName,@Payload String message);

    public void write(@Header("fileName")String fileName,@Payload File file);
}
```

I run the application and its everything ok

```
public class AppConfig implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Autowired
    FileReaderFTP fileWriterFTP;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AppConfig.class, args);
    }

    public void run(ApplicationArguments arg0) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, IOException {
        fileWriterFTP.write("test.txt","test");
    }
}
```

But I can't read files:

```
<int:channel id="ftpInChannel"/>

<int:gateway service-interface="ftpmodule.service.FileReaderFTP"
default-request-channel="ftpInChannel"/>

<int-ftp:inbound-streaming-channel-adapter session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
channel="ftpInChannel" filename-pattern="*.txt"
remote-file-separator="/" remote-directory="/web/">
</int-ftp:inbound-streaming-channel-adapter>

public interface FileReaderFTP {

    public InputStream read(String fileName);

}
@Autowired
FileReaderFTP fileReaderFTP;
InputStream stream = fileReaderFTP.read("test.txt");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the way the inbound channel adapter works - it is a polled adapter that will send the input stream to a channel.

For your scenario, you need to use an outbound gateway with a streaming GET command.

See [the gateway documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-outbound-gateway).

You will also need some more code because with a streaming request, you are responsible for closing the session that the input stream belongs to.